# git local repo, multiple remotes, can't push changed master

Tags: git, github

I'm struggling to push changes to a Git repo. There is a remote repo on GitHub that I have cloned. I have a fork also on GitHub and a single local repo which contains branches `origin/master` which is the original repo and `phil/master` which is the master branch of my fork.

I created a branch to follow my master:

```
$ git checkout -b phil-master phil/master
```

However, after commiting some changes to phil-master and attempting to push them, I get

```
$git push phil
Everything up-to-date
```

but `git status` gives

```
$ git status
# On branch phil-master
# Your branch is ahead of 'remotes/phil/master' by 1 commit.
```

I tried

```
$ git branch --set-upstream remotes/phil/master
```

but this hasn't made any difference.

How can I get my changes to be pushed onto `phil/master`?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `git push <repo>` pushes "branches having the same name in both ends".

See the git-config(1) manual page for the description of `push.default` setting if you want to change the default push behaviour. You could possibly be interested in setting the following:

```
$ git config --global push.default upstream
```

.. which will set up git to "push the current branch to its upstream branch". Thanks to the --global flag it is effective for all git repositories for that user.

Alternatively as a one-shot solution you can ask git specifically to push your branch like this:

```
$ git push phil phil-master
```

Comment: That's great - the first solution worked perfectly, although I omitted the --global flag to just add this behaviour for this repo. I had already tried the second solution and it just pushes my phil-master branch to the phil repo, it doesn't merge it with phil/master.